# What is this vacuum tool in cleaning chairs of car?

Tags: cleaning

The tool is [here](https://www.instagram.com/p/BR6Vkg4j2pa/?taken-by=iandoit) in action in one user's Instagram video. It is some sort of vacuum machine. However, my normal vacuum cleaner is not so powerful. I am not sure if there is any chemicals used in such a cleaning procedure because I have never managed to clean such a way.

Comment: It appears to be an upholstery  cleaner/shampoo attachment. They are typically used with a machine specific for doing this task. They apply then remove the cleaning mixture.

Comment: @mikes Can you have any link to a product in Amazon, please, about the product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is the exact machine used in the video
[Daimer Carpet Cleaning](https://www.daimer.com/carpet-cleaners/xtreme-power-xph-5900iu.htm?gclid=COrzwYTniNMCFZKIswodltEC2g)

This is obviously a professional tool which would be out of range of most consumers except for professional service companies. Here is an Amazon alternative. [BISSELL Portable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AZBJ1JK)

But to answer your original question, the first link is the one used in the video (pretty darn sure)

Comment: Awesome! And still most cruise companies are not using this device to clean their cabins.

Comment: @Léo Léopold Hertz 준영 Glad to help! Check out this YouTube channel for car cleaning tips. This guy is amazing. [Ammo NYC](https://www.youtube.com/user/AMMONYCdotcom)